# Computer performance reducing on AC Power

Tags: battery

I thought there was something wrong with my computer but thanks to you I realized that running my laptop on only AC power reduces the computer performance. And by the way, is it safe to have laptop battery plugged in all the time while gaming? Because gaming causes heat and heat is bad for batteries.

Comment: Most laptops depend on the battery to provide "peak" power, even when running on AC.  With the battery not installed the CPU is "throttled" to prevent overloading the power supply.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a setting in the BIOS and/or your OS Environment. This would not be abnormal to experience as you have described. My laptop functions similarly when no AC is present and only running on battery power. This is typically by design. However, in your case, typically people do not remove the battery of their laptop and only run on AC. This could be throwing false or NULL signals to your OS which is causing the downclocking of your GPU/CPU. Typically, you can keep your AC plugged in with the battery (under load or normal use). While it isn't great for the battery to have the charge coming to it 24/7, newer laptops will stop trying to push a charge current to the battery once it is fully charged. If anything else, it will send a trickle charge. Personally, I would keep the battery in and use the AC. Unless you have had heat issues in the past, I wouldn't worry about it too much. Also, always keep your laptop well ventilated (don't cover the fan/exhaust slots).